# Progress Bar to prevent repeated WebForm Submissions?

Tags: webforms

I'm getting duplicate webform submissions from what I call "Happy Clickers". I would like to implement a progress bar when someone submits a webform to prevent them from clicking multiple times. I tried the pgbar module, but it's not the solution that I am looking for.

Can anyone recommend a Drupal module to accomplish this? I'm using Drupal 7.

Thanks-in-Advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to limit Happy Clickers, in the webform go to Form settings and there are options for Total submissions limit & Per user submission limit. I would suggest changing the Per user submission limit to once every minute.

Comment: But does that stop them from click,click,click they just keep hitting the Submit repeatably. I need to disable any further clicks and display a progress bar until the submission is complete.

Comment: AFAIK that will require a JavaScript solution to disable the submit button once pressed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click

Answer (score 0):

Used the Hide_Submit module to hide the submit button while the webform is being processed.

Problem solved!